# RxJava : retrieve data from database and return a list

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I use RxJava in my Android project, I want to retrieve all entities User from a table using RxJava asynchronously and return the list List to an adapter `myAdapter(Context context, List<User> users)`.

But now I can only have `Single<User>`, how can I get the list **directly** and put it into my adapter ?

My code:

```
// here vm.getUserList() should return a List<User>
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, vm.getUserList());
...
```

And in my vm:

```
public Single<List<User>> getUserList() {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> myDatabaseRepository.getUsers());
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code? It will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Jaime Suárez Hi I posted my code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call the users method and handle the success/error in the corresponding method.

```
getUserList()
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .doOnSuccess(new Consumer<List<User>>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(List<User> users) throws Exception {
         // fill adapter
         MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, users);
      }
   })
   .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
         // handle error
      }
   });
```

Yes, this is the normal way of retrieving the data from the database/network. You expose from the repository the Observables/Singles, then you subscribe to them and receive the data in the success/error methods to show in the UI to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void fetchUser() {
            ('function returning Single<List<User>>').subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onFail);
}

private void onSuccess(List<User> users) {
    //handle user model here
}

private void onFail(Throwable t) {
    //handle error here
}
```

Comment: I want to pass List<User> directly into my adapter without passing onSuccess(), is that possible ? In fact the adapter should search for the List<User> not the opposite

Comment: How are you getting Single<User> as you mentioned?

Comment: It should be actually Single<List<User>> so that you will get List<User> in onSuccess method callback of RxJava. Then you can notify it to the adapter

Comment: Hi, I get Single<List<User>> using return Single.fromCallable(() -> myDatabaseRepository.getUsers());

Comment: Exactly. So use the method which returns the Single<List<User>> in the code I posted. I will edit the code correspondingly.

Comment: Yes I can notify the adapter in onSuccess, but in my opinion the adapter should launch the Rxjava call to fetch data and not the opposite. What if you have two lists that you should retrieve to construct an adapter ?

Comment: If you have two lists you want to compose, you can use an Observable.zip to merge both observables into one.

Comment: @Jaime Suárez Hi, can you confirm it's common to pass objects to adapter in onSuccess() ? It's weird but if it's common it's ok for me

Comment: @brest1007 Although other ways may exist, this method is not considered to be weird as per my opinion.